# Selecting multiple counted fields in T-SQL query

Tags: t-sql

I am stuck on a SQL query, where I need to count the number of different values in a field.

My query is:

```sql
SELECT 
     Area
     , (SELECT count(TestResult)  FROM TestRun WHERE TestResult = 'PASS' AND TestRun.CreatedDate > '2019-11-18 01:00:00') as [Passed]
     , (SELECT count(TestResult)  FROM TestRun WHERE TestResult = 'FAIL' AND TestRun.CreatedDate > '2019-11-18 01:00:00') as [Failed]
     , (SELECT count(TestResult)  FROM TestRun WHERE TestResult = 'NOTRUN' AND TestRun.CreatedDate > '2019-11-18 01:00:00') as [NotRun]
FROM TestRun
WHERE dbo.TestRun.CreatedDate > '2019-11-18 01:00:00'
GROUP BY dbo.TestRun.Area, TestRun.TestResult, TestRun.CreatedDate
```

But The Results I get back look like this, instead of individual values:
[image: Image of test counts, by result]

Comment: I see, the answer is actually correct, but it's posting the aggregated value for each record it finds.  How would I see one row of data for each area? (There are multiple areas, fyi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own fields using case and then sum them.

```
SELECT Area
, SUM(CASE WHEN TestResult = 'PASS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Passed
, SUM(CASE WHEN TestResult = 'FAIL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failed
, SUM(CASE WHEN TestResult = 'NOTRUN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotRun
FROM TestRun
WHERE CreatedDate > '2019-11-18 01:00:00'
GROUP BY Area
```

Comment: And this will be orders of magnitude faster than running sub-queries.

Comment: Aside: The term of art for this is _conditional aggregation_.